# Do not include in random number

Tags: javascript, random

I am having some trouble with my javascript code. My code is meant to be able to see if a checkbox is unchecked, and if it is, it will never come up as a random number.

```
<style>
.checkboxdiv {
    display: block;
    margin-left:20px;
    color: #ddd;    
}
</style>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lotto = function(){
    var TotalMoney = 240;
    var unsold = [];
    var R1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 24) + 1);
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = R1;    
    var R2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 24) + 1);
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = R2;
    if (R2 == R1) {
        var R2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 24) + 1);
        document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = R2;
    }
    for (var i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        if (!document.getElementById('P' + i).checked) {
            TotalMoney = TotalMoney - 10;
            unsold.push(i);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < unsold.length; i++) {
        if (R1 == unsold[i]) {
            var R1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 24) + 1);
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = R1;    
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < unsold.length; i++) {
        if (R2 == unsold[i]) {
            var R2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 24) + 1);
            document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = R2;    
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('TotalMoney').innerHTML = TotalMoney;
    var prize1 = TotalMoney * 0.5;
    document.getElementById('money1').innerHTML = prize1;
    var prize2 = TotalMoney * 0.2;
    document.getElementById('money2').innerHTML = prize2;
    var profit = TotalMoney * 0.3;
    document.getElementById('prof').innerHTML = profit;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar1">
        <div style="margin-top: 20px" class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="heckboxs" id="P1" checked="checked" />1</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="heckboxs" id="P2" checked="checked" />2</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P3" checked="checked" />3</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P4" checked="checked" />4</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P5" checked="checked" />5</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P6" checked="checked" />6</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P7" checked="checked" />7</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P8" checked="checked" />8</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P9" checked="checked" />9</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P10" checked="checked" />10</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P11" checked="checked" />11</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P12" checked="checked" />12</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P13" checked="checked" />13</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P14" checked="checked" />14</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P15" checked="checked" />15</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P16" checked="checked" />16</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P17" checked="checked" />17</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P18" checked="checked" />18</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P19" checked="checked" />19</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P20" checked="checked" />20</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P21" checked="checked" />21</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P22" checked="checked" />22</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P23" checked="checked" />23</div>
        <div class="checkboxdiv"><input type="checkbox" class="chckboxs" id="P24" checked="checked" />24</div>


    <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto"><p>Total Money: $<span id="TotalMoney"></span></p></div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto"><p>Profit: $<span id="prof"></span></p></div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto"><p>1st Place: <span id="1"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Prize Money: $<span id="money1"></span></p></div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto"><p>2nd Place: <span id="2"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Prize Money: $<span id="money2"></span></p></div>
    <button  style="margin-left: 20px" onclick="lotto()">Lotto!</button>
    <span id="test"></span>
    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the post...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you click "edit" you can add the code to your question, or add a reasonable extract of your code that highlights where you're having trouble. If you wish to also include a link to the full code, may I suggest using http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com, because at those two sites we can see your code actually working (or see the errors for ourselves).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if it is checked then generate a random number? If so this will work: http://jsfiddle.net/5zBg6/3/

```
var choices = [];
$("#run").click(function(){
    choices = [];
    $( "input:checkbox:checked" ).each(function( i,value ) {
        choices.push($(this).attr('value')); 
    });
    var randomItem = Math.ceil(Math.random()*choices.length)-1;
    alert(choices[randomItem]);
});
```

Updated to pick a random value of the chosen checked items.

Comment: You might like to mention that the OP would need to use jQuery for this to work. Also, I believe the OP's intention is to randomly select from the numbers associated with the checkboxes that are actually checked.

Comment: Yes that is what i mean. Sorry if it was unclear Spencer Wieczorek

Comment: It's also possible for `Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)` to return `0`. I don't think that's your intent?

Comment: @thgaskell: It was, I just used any constant and a random. Changing the code right now, will have it up in a bit.

Comment: Oh, what I meant was [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). So there's a chance you will get `Math.ceil(0)` (which will return `0`). You should use `Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + min` instead.